# How to check if a symlink, not the file it points to, exists in Rust?

Tags: rust

`Path::exists` is not suitable, since its documentation states:

> This function will traverse symbolic links to query information about the destination file. In case of broken symbolic links this will return false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::fs::read_link`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.read_link.html) seems what you want.

> This function will return an error in the following situations, but is not limited to just these cases:
>
> - path is not a symbolic link.
> - path does not exist.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use `std::fs::symlink_metadata` ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.21.0/std/fs/fn.symlink_metadata.html)).

> Query the metadata about a file without following symlinks.
>   This function will return an error ... [when] `path` does not exist.

The upside of this is that the returned `Metadata` struct contains a `FileType` struct ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.21.0/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html#method.file_type)), which you can query about whether the path is a plain file, a directory or a symbolic link. This could be useful if the possible outcomes were more than "link exists" and "link does not exist".